# `transform_reduce` returns incorrect value, possibly rounding up the actual result

Tags: c++

I have the following vectors:

```
vector<double> X {0.95, 3.75};
vector<double> p {3, 0};
```

I want to perform the following operation:

```
(0.95^3)*(3.75^0) // = 0.8573749999999999
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
std::transform_reduce(
  std::execution::par,
  X.begin(),
  X.end(),
  p.end(),
  1.0,
  &pow,
  std::multiplies()
);
```

and is returning a value of `1`.

How can I fix the current code so I get the expected/correct result.

Comment: You are making multiple errors. 1. The overload you are seeking does not exist. 2. You should not take the address of `pow`. Since the first one is obvious, please show what the call was _intended_ to do and someone may correct it for you. The second one is most subtle. You need to wrap the call in a proxy.

Comment: Why `p.end()` here ? Weren't you mean `p.begin()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your second range should start at `p.begin()`, not `p.end()`.
2. Your reducer should be `multiplies` and your transform function should be `pow`, but you've transposed the arguments

```cpp
std::transform_reduce(
  std::execution::par,
  X.begin(),
  X.end(),
  p.begin(),
  1.0,
  std::multiplies(),
  [](double x, double p) { return std::pow(x, p); }
);
```